# How to see brief location in the code in C/C++ mode

Tags: c++, c, imenu

While editing a long C++ file, I use `rtags` to jump around. It would be very handy for me to know where I am in terms of where the cursor is relative to the classes-functions. For example, it would be great if I could have something similar to `imenu` that would echo `Class A -> function F` for the current position of the cursor.

I believe that some version of this does exist even in vanilla Emacs, it's only that I cannot find it.

Comment: Related, showing doxygen section in the mode-line: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/59508/2418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `which-function-mode` (which is indeed a standard feature).

Comment: That is what I need. Do you probably know how can I scroll the mode line to the right, since I usually have my screen vertically split and the end of my mode line is not visible?